# NA's when converting serial number into date in R

Tags: r, as.date

After importing an excel sheet into R, I found that all dates format has been changed to serial number. I tried to use the very simple code as below, however I get NA's instead of date.

Reproducible example is (df):

```
structure(list(X1 = c("31020", "31021", "31022", "31023", "31026", 
"31027"), X2 = c("197.95000000000002", "186.8", "190.51", "195.16", 
"199.81", "202.59"), X3 = c("90.070000000000007", "89.820000000000007", 
"87.36", "87.61", "90.56", "89.820000000000007"), X4 = c("20.43", 
"20.43", "20.43", "20.43", "20.43", "20.43"), X5 = c("24.54", 
"23.97", "23.97", "24.38", "24.38", "24.38")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I used is

```
df[,1]<-as.Date(df[,1], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I tested `as.Date` with individual serial number after specifying the `origin` and it works fine. However when I try to convert the whole first column of (df) at once, it gives those NA's

I am on Mac OS 10.10 and R 3.1.1

Comment: Couldn't find `-` in the example data showed.

Comment: You need to use `as.numeric`, i.e., `as.numeric(df[,1])` in order to pass it to `as.Date` and then you need to specify the `origin` (which is obviously not "1970-01-01"). Also, no need in `format` here. Something like `as.Date(as.numeric(df[,1]), origin = "1970-01-01")` should work but with the *correct* origin

Comment: @akrun Do you mean in the serial number?

Comment: @Ahmed Salhin I was also thinking in the same way as David Arenburg, but got confused by the origin as I got `2054` as Year.  If `year` is 1984, then `as.Date(as.numeric(df[,1]), origin='1900-01-01')`

Comment: Please see the examples in `?as.Date` for a small discussion about the 'correct' `origin` in dates given as number of days since the origin in Excel.

Comment: For reference, in my Excel2010, Windows, those dates are in December 1984, and `0` is , interestingly enough, "Saturday, January 0, 1900" ("1904 date system" is NOT enabled) .  See if that matches your source values.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that works fine, only the `origin` is what I have changed.

Comment: @Henrik the examples say that `origin` would be "1899-12-30" for Windows Excel and "1904-01-01" Mac Excel. I tried both and the one for Windows Excel exactly matched my dates, however, I am using Mac Excel.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "1899-12-30" works for me.

Comment: @akrun the year in my sample is 1984 but and but it seems there is a difference of a couple of days when setting `origin` to be '1900-01-01'.